# How to read CODE_128 with length = 50 characters ionic Cordova plugin barcode scanner

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

i'm trying to read a code bar with a length of 50 characters.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to do that.

I changed  more than one plugin with the same results (@red-mobile/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-qr-barcode-scanner-sdk33?activeTab=readme).
I set the option "formats": "QR_CODE, CODE_128". Doesn't work.
If I set "formats" to default, the plugin read the codebar as UPC_E: it's wrong.
If I set the format correctly (I know for sure that's CODE_128), the scanner doesn't recognize the code bar.
What could I do?

I'm using ionic cordova (10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)), cordova-android@11, node 14.16.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across several issues pertaining to any barcode plugins that can be an issue:

- Barcode label is too faded
- Barcode is etched in product not a plastic label
- Camera has no way to focus on barcode

usually you need to place the phone in different positions and angles to hopefully scan the barcode, which is not an ideal case.

Now I use: [@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-mlkit/tree/main/packages/barcode-scanning). It offers a way better experience than other barcode plugins and it works! Author provides example project as well!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You've right. If i scan from a paper and the print is not perfect, the reader won't read the code. If I scan on the screen, everything's ok. PS. I cannot use Capacitor 'cause it's a company project - but for my personal projects I will follow your tip. Thanks again.